# In HHL algorithm, how to find the angle of rotation of ancilla qubits?

Tags: hhl-algorithm

In HHL algorithm, after the quantum phase estimation, what is the angle of rotation i.e. what is the value of $\theta$ in R$_y$($\theta$) that is used in rotating ancilla qubit? How to find this angle of rotation without knowing the eigenvalues of matrix $A$?
Is there any general method to find this angle of rotation for any $n$x$n$ Hermitian matrix $A$?

[image]

Comment: note that you can use equations in posts via mathjax, see e.g. https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/49/55

Comment: That's why it's controlled off "register". That tells you (approximately) the eigenvalue and so you compute the rotation angle based upon that.

Comment: @glS , thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the question.

Comment: @DaftWullie Can you explain in detail what you want to say. Better to explain with an example.